# Jquery won't assign styles in a loop

Tags: jquery, css

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("stack").each(function(){
    styles = $(this).parse_attr();
    $(this).convert_el().css(styles);
  });
});
(function($){
  $.fn.parse_attr = function(){
    if(this.length === 0 ){
        return null;
    }
    tag_types = ["class","id","name"];
    css_hash = {};
    $.each(this[0].attributes,function(){
        attrib = this.name.split(":")
        if( !($.inArray(attrib[0],tag_types) >= 0) ){
            if($.isNumeric(attrib[1])){
                css_hash[attrib[0]] = attrib[1] + "px";
            }else{
                css_hash[attrib[0]] = attrib[1];
            }
        }
    });
    return css_hash;
};
}(jQuery));

(function($){
$.fn.convert_el = function(){
    if(this.length === 0 ){
        return null;
    }
    klasses = this.prop("tagName").toLowerCase();
    tag_types = ["class","id","name"];
    $.each(this[0].attributes,function(){
        attrib = this.name.split(":")
        if($.inArray(attrib[0],tag_types) >= 0 ){
            klasses = klasses + " " + attrib[1].replace(/"/g,"");
        }
    });
    this.replaceWith($("<div class='"+ $.trim(klasses) + "'>" + this.html() + "</div>"));
    return this;
}
}(jQuery));
```

If I do not iterate over the "stack" element it will apply the styles but for some reason it ignores .css(styles); during iteration. Any ideas?

Also please do not ask why I am trying to do things this way I am just experimenting with a conceptual idea of passing non existent html tags through jquery to dynamically develop a web page using things like

```
<stack class:center margin:100 color:red background-color:#FFF></stack>
```

It should then parse these values into a style and apply it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the problem is the replacing. The original element is removed, so you can't change its styles but `$.fn.convert_el` still returns it.

Changing the function a little bit gives the desired result.

```
newDiv = $("<div class='"+ $.trim(klasses) + "'>" + this.html() + "</div>") 
this.replaceWith(newDiv);
return newDiv;
```